# In javascript is there a way to write a conditional on the property of an object several layers deep without checking each layer?

Tags: javascript

I have an object:

```
let someObject = {
  someKey: {
    otherKey: {
      key3: {
         youGetThePoint: null
      }
    }
  }
};
```

If I write:

```
if (someObject.someKey.otherKey.key3.youGetThePoint) {
   doStuff();
}
```

and some method removes `key3` from the object in `otherKey` then this conditional breaks.

Is there a way to write this conditional without linking several `&&` together or nesting several conditionals to check each layer?
i.e. avoiding:

```
if (someObject && someObject.someKey && some...
```

Comment: Simplest way is to wrap it in try catch block

Comment: Use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining). `someObject?.someKey?.otherKey?.key3?.youGetThePoint`

Comment: @Ivar It absolutely does.  Thank you very much.  I guess when I was looking for the answer I didn't know how to word it properly.

Answer (score -1):

```js
let someObject = {
  someKey: {
    otherKey: {
      key3: {
         youGetThePoint: null
      }
    }
  }
};
function objNestedCheck(someObject, someKey, otherKey, key3, youGetThePoint) {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);

  for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
    if (!someObject|| !someObject.hasOwnProperty(args[i])) {
      return false;
    }
    someObject= someObject[args[i]];
  }
  return true;
}

objNestedCheck(someObject , 'someKey', 'otherKey', 'key3', 'youGetThePoint');

if (objNestedCheck(someObject , 'someKey', 'otherKey', 'key3', 'youGetThePoint')) {
  // you can do your stuff here 
  doStuff();
}
```

using ES6 features and recursion

```
function checkNested(someObject , someKey,  ...rest) {
  if (someObject === undefined) return false
  if (rest.length == 0 && someObject .hasOwnProperty(someKey)) return true
  return checkNested(someObject [level], ...rest)
}
if (checkNested(someObject , someKey,  ...rest)) {
      // you can do your stuff here 
      doStuff();
}
```